# Можно ли перегрузить оператор static_cast вне класса?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Можно ли перегрузить оператор static_cast вне класса? К примеру операторы +, - и тд, можно перегрузить в локальном нэймспейсе не как член класса, можно сделать что то подобное например с оператором `operator int();` ?

Comment: Почему бы и нет?

Comment: @Harry, а какая сигнатура ?

Comment: Если целевой тип - класс, то можно добавит конструктор в этот класс...

Answer (score 1):

[Конечно](https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/5.15.php).

```
[explicit] operator type() [const]
```

[Например](https://ideone.com/2iYjva) :):

```
class R
{
public:
    operator int() const { return rand(); }
};


int main()
{
    R r;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        cout << i + r << endl;
}
```

Comment: хотелось бы не помещать перегрузку в сам класс

Comment: А вот такое - вряд ли...